# Using double quotes on str_replace

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `str_replace` to change my code:

```
$changeli = "li id=\"head{$raiz}\" class=\"head\"";
$changeli2 = "li id=\"foot{$raiz}\" class=\"foot\"";

echo $changeli; // result li id="head-all" class="head"
echo $changeli2; // result li id="foot-all" class="foot"

$footer = str_replace($changeli, $changeli2, $footer );
```

It doesn't work, but when I remove the text up to the double quotes, it works, as follows:

```
$changeli = "head{$raiz}";
$changeli2 = "foot{$raiz}";

echo $changeli; // result head-all
echo $changeli2; // result foot-all

$footer = str_replace($changeli, $changeli2, $footer );
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the content of $footer before this code?

Comment: The echo the footer is id="<li id="head-all" class="head"><p>The news of the....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better yet, try to use `'` instead of `"` for the outer quote so you don't have to escape it at all. And concatenate $raiz with your string. The problem is most likely characters that should be escaped in html.

Try this, this works ([see this code exactly here](http://codepad.org/Bta73SXW)):

```
$changeli = 'li id="head'.$raiz.'" class="head"';
$changeli2 = 'li id="foot'.$raiz.'" class="foot"';

// value of $raiz is "-all" at this point (for clarity of code)
echo $changeli; // result should be li id="head-all" class="head"
echo $changeli2; // result should be li id="foot-all" class="foot"

$footer = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace(htmlspecialchars($changeli), htmlspecialchars($changeli2), htmlspecialchars($footer)));
```

Comment: But the single quotes will prevent $raiz from being evaluated in `$changeli` and `$changeli2`

Comment: @David White Yes, but that is his point, as per how I understand it. And that is why I believe it does not work as he wants it. Because he wants to be literal and not use a string, but literally the characters `$raiz`.

Comment: From the comments in his code, `$raiz` appears to have the value `"-all"`.  I'm assuming he means for that to be evaluated in the expression.  But, hard to say from the OP.

Comment: @David White Aha! You are right. I fixed my code accordingly. This should fully work for him.

Comment: I wanna change the id value, but i can´t only look for the name of the ID and change, because I have others instances with this text, so I have to look for this value (id="head-all), I acomplish this with $changeli, but, when i use this in the str_replace this won´t work

Comment: @Alê Moraes -- OK, I fixed the code so it concatenates your string within the search string. Try now.

Comment: I try your code, the $changeli gives me id="head-all, but the str_replace don´t replace the text to id="foot-all

Comment: Please post the value of $footer before this code runs.

Comment: @Alê Moraes -- What is in the $footer before? Put this line in the code before the `str_replace`:                      `echo $footer;`

Comment: The echo of the footer is id="<li id="head-all" class="head"><p>The news of the....

Comment: And to be sure, what is the value of `$raiz` ?

Comment: Do you think I can convert the $changeli, $changeli2 and the $footer, with the html_entity_decode and then convert back?

Comment: Special characters may be the problem.  Can you run these 4 commands and list the four lines of output you get:  `print "footer: " . implode(' ',array_map('dechex', array_map('ord', str_split($footer)))) . "\n";`  `print "raiz: " . implode(' ',array_map('dechex', array_map('ord', str_split($raiz)))) . "\n";`  `print "changeli: " . implode(' ',array_map('dechex', array_map('ord', str_split($changeli)))) . "\n";`  `print "changeli2: " . implode(' ',array_map('dechex', array_map('ord', str_split($changeli2)))) . "\n";`

Comment: Agreed something else is wrong. My code above fully works. See this: [link](http://codepad.org/M8sJcVrT)

Comment: @Alê Moraes -- OK, here is the fix. Use the escape codes around all your strings, see the updated code above, but the **str_replace** line should be `$footer = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace(htmlspecialchars($changeli), htmlspecialchars($changeli2), htmlspecialchars($footer)));`

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:

```
$changeli = 'li id="head'.$raiz.'" class="head"';
$changeli2 = 'li id="foot'.$raiz.'" class="foot"';

echo $changeli; // result li id="head-all" class="head"
echo $changeli2; // result li id="foot-all" class="foot"
$footer = '';

$footer = str_replace($changeli, $changeli2, $footer );
```

Comment: It gives me the same problem, the $changeli prints correctly the id="head-all" calss="head", but the str_replace don´t change

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said the values of `$footer` and `$raiz` are, it's hard to see what's going wrong.  For example this program:

```
<?php

$footer = 'id="<li id="head-all" class="head"><p>The news of the...';
$raiz   = '-all';

$changeli  = "li id=\"head{$raiz}\" class=\"head\"";
$changeli2 = "li id=\"foot{$raiz}\" class=\"foot\"";

print "(BEFORE) Footer: $footer\n";
$footer = str_replace($changeli, $changeli2, $footer );
print "(AFTER)  Footer: $footer\n";
```

produces this output:

```
(BEFORE) Footer: id="<li id="head-all" class="head"><p>The news of the...
(AFTER)  Footer: id="<li id="foot-all" class="foot"><p>The news of the...
```